# Ajax not working on a jsf 2.2 simple page

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a simple jsf 2.2 page and  cant figure out why ajax is not working, i searched the web but couldnt find a solution, i'm only showing the relevant part here... these are inside a multpart/form-data form. Nothing happens, the outputText is not shown on page when i toggle the selectBooleanCheckBox.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{worksheetEditBean.sendMail}"><h:outputLabel value="Send Email"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" render="mailPnl" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>


<h:panelGroup id="mailPnl">
    <h:outputText rendered="#{worksheetEditBean.sendMail}">Hello</h:outputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: How looks the rendered html source code?

Comment: Just a span with id mailPnl and nothing inside it

Comment: And what is the value of `{worksheetEditBean.sendMail}`?

Comment: Well, i expect jsf to toggle it to true or false depending on the checkbox state, i'm not setting this flag anywhere on my code.

Comment: I figured it out, the text of the output text cant be inside the element, it has to be on the value attribute, so changing to <h:outputText value="Hello" rendered="#{worksheetEditBean.sendMail}"/> does the job. Thank you reporter.